# Why does 'we' have one 'e' while 'see' has two?

Tags: orthography, phonics

I am wondering why the words *me* and *we* have one *'e'*, even though the word *see* has two.

Comment: Different etymologies

Comment: There's not really a good reason - lots of words have single "e", lots have double "e". "be" and "see" had similar forms in Old English - *bieon, bian, bion; sean, sian, sea, sion* - but are now spelt differently.

Comment: Why does *we* have one e and *wee* have two?